# Operand should contain 1 column(s) in my sql query

Tags: mysql, sql

Can someone help me with this query?

```
    SELECT ((SELECT t6.`idreserva`, t5.`sala`, t6.`data`,t3.`inicio`, t4.`fim`, t6.`atividade`
FROM `req_reserva_detail` AS t1
INNER JOIN `req_material_tempo` AS t3 ON (t1.`idtempoInicio` = t3.`idtempo`)
INNER JOIN `req_material_tempo` AS t4 ON (t1.`idtempoFim` = t4.`idtempo`)
INNER JOIN `req_material_sala` AS t5 ON (t1.`idsala` = t5.`idsala`)
INNER JOIN `req_reservas` AS t6 ON (t1.`idreserva` = t6.`idreserva`)
INNER JOIN `utilizador` AS t7 ON (t6.`idutilizador` = t7.`idutilizador`) WHERE t6.`idutilizador` = 670 AND t6.`data` >= CURDATE() ORDER BY  DATA ASC),
(SELECT nome FROM `req_reserva_detail` AS t1, `req_material_equipamento` AS t2 WHERE t1.`idequipamento` = t2.`idequipamento` GROUP BY nome))
```

It gives that error and i don't get how to fix that...

Regards

UPDATE

Schema

[image]

Comment: What error are you getting? Show your schema?

Comment: What is the exact error message you're getting?

Comment: I have the error operand should only contain one column

Answer (score 0):

```
(SELECT t6. idreserva,
                t5. sala,
                t6. data,
                t3. inicio,
                t4. fim,
                t6. atividade
           FROM req_reserva_detail AS t1
          INNER JOIN req_material_tempo AS t3
             ON (t1. idtempoInicio = t3. idtempo)
          INNER JOIN req_material_tempo AS t4
             ON (t1. idtempoFim = t4. idtempo)
          INNER JOIN req_material_sala AS t5
             ON (t1. idsala = t5. idsala)
          INNER JOIN req_reservas AS t6
             ON (t1. idreserva = t6. idreserva)
          INNER JOIN utilizador AS t7
             ON (t6. idutilizador = t7. idutilizador)
          WHERE t6. idutilizador = 670
            AND t6. data >= CURDATE()
          ORDER BY DATA ASC)
```

This subquery of yours returns 5 columns, but this is used as a subquery and mySQL expects it to return only one column

Comment: It works but is not what i'm looking for, i need to return in that query the "`req_material_equipamento`, it should return the values liek an invoice, that table "req_reserva_detail" is like a orderDetail table